# Put a Azure Web App and a Virtual Machine inside the same Vnet on Azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a subnet on Azure with a virtual machine inside.
I then created a Web App and tried to integrate it on this same SubNet.

An error message told me that the Subnet must be empty to perform this operation.

I then decide to take out the Virtual Machine (which I temporarily place elsewhere) and then integrate the Web App on the Subnet. The operation was successful.

I then try to put my Virtual Machine back on the Subnet but I again get an error message indicating that an external resource is already present on this subnet.

My question is simple: is it possible to place a Virtual Machine and a Web App in the same Subnet? And if this is not possible, why? And what alternatives are possible?

Is it a problem with an insufficiently large address range? For information, my subnet has a range of 26 addresses max.

Thanks

Comment: hello @stevenPF, AFAIK its not possible to assign both resources in a single subnet. it can be same VNET. and both will be able to communicate with each other if they are in same vnet as the address space will be same.

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBal-MT. Thank you for your reply. It will prevent me from wasting time to increase the address space of my subnet. Is this a limitation specific to Subnet? to the Web App? Because I remember that on a previous project, I had a Subnet (classic in ASM) with a virtual machine and a cloud service inside.

Comment: answered the difference and limitation for the above in the second part of the answer .

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT : Thank you for this complete and precise answer. I understand a lot better now :)

While experimenting this morning, I indeed noticed that after adding a Web App on a SubNet, the "ServerFarms" delegation was automatically assigned to the subnet.

So I'm going to create a new subnet for the Web App :)

Thanks again.

Comment: Np! Glad to be of help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to place a Virtual Machine and a Web App in the same
> Subnet? And if this is not possible, why? And what alternatives are
> possible?
>
> Is it a problem with an insufficiently large address range? For
> information, my subnet has a range of 26 addresses max.

**Ans:** As already commented , Two resource Providers can't be in the same subnet. It will show you the below error:

> [image]

So , as a solution you can create a new subnet in the same Virtual Network and integrate it with the Web app . And as the VM and App are present in the same Virtual network , they will be able to connect/communicate with each other.

---

> Is this a limitation specific to Subnet? to the Web App? Because I
> remember that on a previous project, I had a Subnet (classic in ASM)
> with a virtual machine and a cloud service inside

**Ans**: VM and Cloud Services are almost same resources providers i.e. `Compute` , the providers are `Microsoft.Compute` and `Microsoft.ClassicCompute`. And there is no requirement for  delegation for a `Compute` provider in a subnet.

Since all the Classic Providers have been deprecated , you will be now using ARM providers , So the provider for App service is `Microsoft.Web` and when you use the subnet for a specific provider like Web ,Sql, etc. it gets delegated and then can only be used by the specific resource provider resources only .

**Example :**

I created a Subnet in the VNet to be used by App and added Integration with Subnet for the web APP:

[image]

After the integration if you check the subnet inside the vnet , you will notice the delegation added :

[image]

**Note:** As the delegation is done for `ServerFarms`, you will be now able to only add the webapps in the same subnet and no other resources as the delegation for a single resource provider only.

**Reference:**

For in-depth clarification on the **Subnet Delegation** part you can refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/subnet-delegation-overview).